# java: println(new String(byte[] b) ) equivalent in C++

Tags: java, c++, string, arrays

I'm kind-of converting a program from Java to C++. 
In Java I read an `InputStream` using a `byte` array, say `b`.
Than I need to print the ASCII characters so I use `new String(b)`. Now, I want to do something similar with C++;

I read a stream and put my data in an unsigned char array, but when I print it I get many strange symbols that, instead, are not shown in Java

Thank for helping

Comment: Can you give the C++ code you are using to print the char array, are you using cout or printf?

Comment: Are these characters appear after the end of the "normal" portion of your string?

Comment: You read the contents you stored with Java? It may be an encoding problem.

Comment: Indeed I don't know exactly what to use in C++. I tried both printf and cout and several conversions and castings.
Yes I read the vector in Java without any problem.

Nope I don't have a "normal" portion of my string only strange characters